# Saving embedded images by replying with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def imageapprove(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.author.id != my_id:
            return
        message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
        attachment = message.attachments[0]
        content = attachment.url
        res = requests.get(content, stream=True)
        with open(f'images\\filename.png', 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, f)
        await ctx.send('image approved')
        print('saving image')
    except:
        await ctx.send('Something went wrong.')
        print('Error(imageapprove command)')
```

This is the command a friend wrote which allows only me to reply to an image and save it to a folder. But it doesn't work when I try it in on an image or gif which was sent using a link . I'm fairly new to python and do not know how to save images or gifs like that without rewriting the whole code.

I tried to find tutorials but I was unable to find a tutorial on how to do the same thing (save by replying to an image with the command). I need help on how to save images and gifs sent by a link

For example if someone sends a message with this link:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1035115107992223746/1109411245720870962/attachment-4.gif

that is a gif. I want to reply to that and save it using the imageapprove command. Same with other images and videos too.

Comment: Are you using discord.py or pycord? If you are using either, please remove the other tag for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_id = ENTER_YOUR_ID_HERE
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    
    try:
        if ctx.author.id != my_id:
            return
        picture_message = await ctx.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
        if picture_message.embeds: 
            picture_url = picture_message.embeds[0].image.url  
        else:
            attachment = picture_message.attachments[0]
            picture_url = attachment.url
        
        filename = picture_url.split('/')[-1]
        res = requests.get(picture_url, stream = True)
        with open(f'images\\{filename}', 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, f)
        await ctx.send('image approved')

    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send('Something went wrong .')
        print(e)
```

So this was my approach of fixing your code, and it worked for me.
Basically it got two cases now:

**First:** (inside if case) Image is posted as an embed.

**Second:** (inside else case) Image is posted as attachment.

It should detect the case and save the image. I guess that you introduced **my_id** earlier in your code? Also make sure that the "image" folder is existing in your scripts directory! I hope this helps..